# DIfference between Spring Kafka and Spring Integration Kafka

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka

Using Kafka as a messaging system in a microservice architecture, I want to know which one is preferred, Spring Kafka, or Spring Integration Kafka and why? Also, on what factors we decide which one to choose?

Comment: It would be better if you could describe more information about your situation.

Comment: @abhi-jain were you able to choose something? Which one did you go with?

Answer (score 6):

[Spring Integration](https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration) - Extends the Spring programming model to support the well-known [Enterprise Integration Patterns](http://www.eaipatterns.com/).

[Spring Integration Kafka](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/1.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/_spring_integration.html) - is an extension module to the [Spring Integration](https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration) Project.

[Spring Integration Kafka](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/1.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/_spring_integration.html) is now based on the [Spring for Apache Kafka](https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka) project.

The [Spring for Apache Kafka (spring-kafka)](https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka) project applies core Spring concepts to the development of Kafka-based messaging solutions.

According to your requirements, if you are developing an application without using Spring Integration, then you need to use the [Spring for Apache Kafka (spring-kafka)](https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka) project or [Spring Cloud Stream (Kafka)](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-stream).

[Spring-Cloud-Stream](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-stream) - is a framework built upon Spring Boot for building message-driven microservices.

[Spring-Kafka vs. Spring-Cloud-Stream (Kafka)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47312542/spring-kafka-vs-spring-cloud-stream-kafka?rq=1)

Comment: Okay, but I am still confused as to which one to pick, spring kafka or spring integration kafka. Are there any specific advantages that spring integration has over spring kafka?

Comment: Spring Integration Kafka has the advantage of providing: Outbound Channel Adapter and Message-Driven Channel Adapter to use them in Spring Integration project.

Comment: With Spring Integration for Apache Kafka version 3.3, you have channels backed by Kafka topics. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#si-channels